# Validate a single word's first three characters with regular expressions

Tags: regex, validation

I have a manager in another department looking for some help concerning regex and I'm extremely unfamiliar with it. I've looked online for some examples and tried partial solutions to my need but haven't found something meeting all my requirements.

Essentially I need a regex that validates strings that:

1. Have only a single word
2. the first three characters must be
   'win'

Comment: Unfortunately, regex doesn't know anything about _Language_ so you won't find one to match a word and is actually impossible, even if you use an encyclopedia and a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might go for:

```
^win\w*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7Jsyqq/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Regex to validate that a string has only a single word (without spaces, numbers or any symbols) and it starts with win:

```
^win[a-zA-Z]*$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lGWz6r/1)

```
// Matches
windows
wind
win
windy

// Doesn't match
win-lose
abcde
door
win win
win#
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure if it was required to match with or without symbols etc etc, but I'll take this too just in case.

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer helped solve your problem, you might want to upvote it. Thanks!